# how to hide textbox when the front checkbox is unchecked using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a function that is used to hide/show textbox right after the checkbox, it works very well untill one day I changed the checkgroup to radiobutton group.
The function that I use is like this

```
var U={
HideOptions: function() {
    $(".option").each(function() {
        if ($(this).closest("li").find(".extra").length) {
            if ($(this).find("input").is(":not(:checked)")) $(this).closest("li").find(".extra").hide();
            $(this).find("input").change(function() {
                $(this).closest("li").find(".extra").toggle().find(".checkgroup .extra").each(function() {
                    $(this).hide();
                    if ($(this).closest("li").find(".option input").is(":checked")) $(this).show();
                });
            });
        }
    });
},
ChangeToRadio: function(selector) {
    var $checkbox = $("input[name=" + selector + "]");
    $checkbox.click(function() {
        if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
            $checkbox.removeAttr('checked');
            $(this).attr('checked', true);
        }
    });
  }
}
```

My html structure is like this

```
<ul class="checkgroup>
    <li>
        <div class="option"> 
             <input id="abc" type="checkbox" value="0" name="chk">Yes
        </div>
        <div class="extra"><input id="abc1"  type="text" value="" > </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="option"> 
             <input id="edf" type="checkbox" value="1" name="chk"> No   
        </div>
        <div class="extra"> <input id="edf1"  type="text" value="" > </div>
    </li>
    ....
 </ul>

 <script type="javascript">
       U.HideOptions();
       U.ChangeToRadio("chk");
 </scripot>
```

Typically, there are several

in , After I use ChangeToRadio function, I found the HideOptions does not works very well. For example, the "extra" part will not be hide if you check other "option".

Any idea?

Comment: Radio buttons are missing in your example.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/f26Vs/

```
$('.option input:checkbox').on('click', function () {
  // you want to use .prop (it returns a boolean and is instant result) 
  //unlike .attr('checked') which has it's issue cross browser checking for true-ness

  var checked = $(this).prop('checked'), 
      _txtArea = $(this).closest('li').find('.extra');            

  if (checked) {
      _txtArea.show();
  }

  else { _txtArea.hide(); }
});
```

​

Answer (score 0):

In your if condition you say `$(this).attr('checked')` but .attr() returns a string not a boolean. Change this to `$(this).attr('checked') == "checked"` and try again.

Also, if you can, try to post a fiddle so we can debug it more than one step at a time. Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, as mcpDESIGNS pointed out, prop is the method you were looking for that would return a boolean